# Why can't I cast `this` to a generic type?

Tags: c#, casting

I'm having an issue wrapping my head around why neither of the following snippets compile.

Visual Studio flags the first one with:

> Cannot convert type 'SomeType' to 'T'
>
> Cast is redundant.

```cs
using System;

public class SomeClass {
    public T Coerce<T>() {
        if (typeof(T) == typeof(SomeClass))
            return (T)this; // <- Error CS0030
        else throw new InvalidCastException();
    }
}
```

Removing the "redundant" cast, however, just changes the error to:

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'SomeOtherClass' to 'T'

```cs
using System;

public class SomeOtherClass {
    public T Coerce<T>() {
        if (typeof(T) == typeof(SomeOtherClass))
            return this; // <- Error CS0029
        else throw new InvalidCastException();
    }
}
```

Comment: It would probably help if you explained *what you're trying to achieve here*.

Comment: `return (T)(object)this;`

Comment: Why would you want to do this?

Comment: @KenWhite I'm trying to return the object my method is called on if the method is called with an appropriate generic type parameter, or perform some other logic if an inappropriate generic type parameter is supplied. This is, of course, not what my actual code looks like, but this is the "Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example" of the issue I was having.

Comment: Don't tell me in a comment. Instead, [edit] your question and explain it there, where it can be seen. You have not explained the problem you're trying to solve, which has to be done before you can post an [mcve] to demonstrate it.

Comment: @KenWhite I explained the problem in both the title and my first sentence: I do not understand why neither (more specifically, the first) of these two snippets compile. I removed the sentence that seems to be confusing the issue.

Comment: No, you haven't explained what you're trying to do. You've explained an error you're getting from something you're doing. You haven't yet explained why you feel the need to do it.

Comment: @KenWhite I'm not going to expand on the context I initially encountered this error in because I am significantly more interested in understanding the *why* of the general case than having somebody provide me an alternate solution to my particular problem.

Comment: OK. That's your choice. I'm not going to revert my downvote for a poor question, or reverse my close vote for it being unclear. This site is about providing content that is relevant to future users, and without a clear statement of the problem you're trying to solve there is no value for those users.

Comment: @KenWhite And that is your choice, though I'd contend that the general case is significantly more relevant to future users than a more specific case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The compiler is telling you exactly what's wrong: you cannot implicitly convert `SomeClass` to `T`, but there are really two things you need to pay attention to.

The first thing is that you cannot implicitly convert to a generic type because the type is not known at compile time. You will have to cast it explicitly or - if you really need implicit conversion - use inheritance.

The second thing is that a little more type information is needed (through constraints) in order to distinguish between value types and reference types. Right now the compiler knows **nothing** about `T`. It might as well be an `int`, which a `class` can never be cast to.

In order to cast a reference type to `T` you need the `class` constraint, and it will work just fine:

```
public class SomeClass
{
    public T Coerce<T>() where T : class
    {
        if (typeof(T) == typeof(SomeClass))
            return this as T;
        else throw new InvalidCastException();
    }
}
```

Now the compiler will also prevent you from doing something like `someClassInstance.Coerce<int>()` and that is the point.

**EDIT**:

As for the example of `(T)(object)this`, this works because you are then no longer casting `this` to `T`. Instead, you cast `this` to `object` (which will always work because it is what **all** other types derive from) and then you cast from `object` to `T` which works for the same reason. You are circumventing the compile-time checks.

You could do this and then call `someClassInstance.Coerce<int>()`, it would give you the exception "Specified cast is not valid." at *runtime*. Using a generic constraint, however, gives you the warning at *compile time*.

If that does not bother you, `return (dynamic)this;` is an even simpler solution. But it kind of defeats the purpose of using generics.

Comment: But then why does `return (T)(object)this;` work without constraints?

Comment: That is just a way of tricking the compiler, pretty closely related to using `dynamic` (it will cause nasty runtime errors if you don't cast to the correct types). An object can be anything: value type, or reference type (and you cannot use `object` as a generic constraint for this reason)

Comment: Updated my answer with a little more explanation specific to the implications of these different approaches

Comment: No `class` constrain is necessary. You could return value types as well: `if (typeof(T) == typeof(int)) return (T)(object)123;`